# Jetpack Compose: Move focus between TextFields using D-Pad without onKeyEvent

Tags: android, focus, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, d-pad

I am building a data-entry application in Jetpack Compose that is intended to be used on a device with a physical keypad.  In the traditional view system, Android's built-in focus traversal works in such a way where, for example, pressing the right D-pad button when the cursor is at the end of an `EditText` will change the focus to the next focusable view to the right.

[default behavior using traditional views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yrk3.gif)

In Jetpack Compose, however, the focus becomes trapped within a `TextField` with no way to traverse to other focusable components using the D-pad.

[default behavior using Compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ2VX.gif)

The only solution I'm aware of is to add an `onKeyEvent` modifier to the `EditText` to manually traverse the focus when key events are fired.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun Fields() {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    Row {
        TextField(
            value = "foo",
            onValueChange = { Unit },
            modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
                if (it.type == KeyEventType.KeyUp && it.key == Key.DirectionRight) {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Right)
                    return@onKeyEvent true
                }
                return@onKeyEvent false
            }
        )
        TextField(value = "bar", onValueChange = { Unit })
    }
}
```

This solution works, but seems inelegant.  It is also not quite optimal because there's a noticeable delay: it seems that `TextField` tries to process text input before handing key events.

Does anybody know whether there's a "proper" way of handling focus with `TextField`, or am I just stuck intercepting key events for now?  Thanks in advance!